# How to float li elements inside multi column list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="baseList">
    <li>
        <ul class="baseListColumn">
            <li>10.09</li>
            <li>My title is here</li>
            <li>Author</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

with the following css:

```
.baseList {
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}

.baseListColumn {
    -moz-column-count:3; 
    -webkit-column-count:3; 
    column-count:3; 

    -moz-column-gap: 10px; 
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px; 
}
```

My problem is, that this centers the content of every li of baseListColumn and gives every column the same width. I would like to make the columns fit it's content apart from the last li element (Author) and float the content of the last li element right.

This is what happens with the current code: http://jsfiddle.net/aLGRJ/1/

```
           10.09                   My title is here                 Author
     asdfasdfasdfasdf           My title is here abababa            Author
```

In fiddle you can even see what happens if the width of the root li is big enough while the equal splitting of the columns is too small to contain some of the content.

This is what I would like to have:

```
10.09                My title is here                                      Author
asdfasdfasdfasdf     My title is here abababa                              Author
```

I can't guarantee that all the columns will always have the same length otherwise I would use absolute positioning and at the same time I don't want to reserve too much unnecessary space for the first column for example. Note I'm planning to use this for lists with more columns than just 3 as well.

Is this one of the cases where a table would be the better solution? Anyways I hope someone can help me, and if there is a better solution to this, I'm always open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a table would be a better solution, not because of the display properties, but because of the nature of your content (remember, organizing content is still the responsibility of HTML).

Take a look at [this page](http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/better-ui-design-proper-use-of-tables.html).

While most of the points are generally agreeable, I tend to focus on two things:

1. Don’t Use Faux Tables (`<p>`, `<div>`, etc.)
2. Tables Should Be Filterable & Sortable (If more then just a few rows)

You can generate all of the CSS yourself... or, use your favorite ECMAScript library to make short work of styling.

Comment: Wow I totally forgot datatables.net seems like this anti table religion has finally taken it's effect on me. I will use tables, I don't know why I was so hesitant.